# is there a faster way than file or mdls to get file types on MacOS X in command line

Tags: macos, shell, find

I want to get the file type of lots of files I'm finding with find.
mime type would suffice, I need to know if they are images, videos, sound, documents etc

So I'm doing

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0  | xargs -0 file --mime-type
```

or

```
find  "$(pwd)" -print0  | xargs -0 mdls -name kMDItemKind
```

But they're "slow" 219 seconds for 55K files for find, 62 for mdls
As I will need to catalog millions of files I need something faster

stat for instance takes 2 seconds (but doesn't provide the file type, there's a Type but that's just folder vs regular file)

Also, I'm not sure if mdls needs the spotlight index to be created before to get the data, or if it recomputes it (which would be safer, as I don't want to rely on a pre-existing index).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running `mdls` (or `file`) once for each file. You can pass multiple files to `mdls` at a time. You can do that without `xargs`.

```
find . -exec mdls -name kMDItemKind {} +

find . -exec file --mime-type {} +
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner, unfortunately though it's faster, it's not taht faster, I gain 1 minute on 10 minutes (another folder), so about 10%. I think the file function itself is slow. As I understand the mime-type is deducted from a magic number, maybe just reading that magic number would be faster, but I don't knwo how

Answer (score 0):

The performance will depend on your disk subsystem and your CPU, but I find I can get the type of 10,000 documents in 3 seconds using **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
find . -print0 | parallel -0 -X mdls -name kMDItemKind -name kMDItemDisplayName
```

Whereas this takes 8 seconds:

```
find . -exec mdls -name kMDItemKind -name kMDItemDisplayName {} +
```

---

You can install **GNU Parallel** on **macOS** with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) using:

```
brew install parallel
```